# Split a string into with colon using regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a string something like this.

```
ars:a:currency (Argentina!: Pesos):
```

i need to split string using colon, but the colon within the brackets should not be split. i need a regex to split this string.

my output should be like

```
ars
a
currency (Argentina!: Pesos)**
```

help is appreciated :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @user1329572: Fair enough, but you do need to know quite a bit about regexen to be able to even conceptualize a solution, so there isn't really much he/she *could* have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single regex *if* you're certain that there won't be any nested parentheses. In that case you can simply split on a colon only if the next parenthesis is not a closing one:

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split(
    "(?x):    # Multiline regex: Match a colon\n" +
    "(?!      # only if it's impossible to match the following at this point:\n" +
    " [^()]*  #  any number of characters besides parentheses\n" +
    " \\)     #  followed by a closing parenthesis\n" +
    ")        # End of lookahead assertion");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work with a single regex. What you could do without complicating too much is `String.split("[()]")`, split the string at every other array index with `:`, and finally concatenate back.

Comment: Given some constraints (no nested parentheses), yes, you can do it in a single regex. (And your solution wouldn't even work on the OP's example)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, I saw your nice solution, the single upvote as of this moment is from me :) And what's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
String[] tok = str.split(":", 3);
```

where `str` is your string.